# UnBound LocalError in Django?

Tags: django, django-errors

I have a registration view in django like this:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, RequestContext, HttpResponseRedirect

def register(request):
    '''Registers the users'''

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/index/') #Returns user to user if successfully logs in

        else:
            form = UserCreationForm()    #Redirects to the UserCreationForm is the form is invalid
            return render_to_response('registration/register.html', {'form':form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

    else:
        return render_to_response('registration/register.html', {'form':form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

When I try to run the view I get `UnBound LocalError`.

```
#Full exception:
Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/zurelsoft/workspace/fyp/summary/views.py" in register
  20.         return render_to_response('registration/register.html', {'form':form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

Exception Type: UnboundLocalError at /
Exception Value: local variable 'form' referenced before assignment
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Method is not post then form is going to the last `else` block

you should define your form outside the `request.POST` like

```
def register(request):
    '''Registers the users'''
    form = UserCreationForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/index/') #Returns user to user if successfully logs in

        else:
            form = UserCreationForm()    #Redirects to the UserCreationForm is the form is invalid
            return render_to_response('registration/register.html', {'form':form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

    else:
        return render_to_response('registration/register.html', {'form':form}, con
```

Comment: Apparently, I can only accept the answer after 15 minutes I posted the question.

Comment: Don't do this. The first `else` clause will now completely remove all your POSTed data and errors in case of invalid entry. Remove that clause completely and execution will fall through to the final else clause, and show any errors in the page.

Comment: Yeah but when I completely remove the first else statement I am getting didn't return an HttpResponse object error.

Answer (score 0):

For `GET` requests you are not defining `form`.

I would suggest to add

```
form = UserCreationForm()
```

before line

```
if request.method == 'POST':
```